# calculate the given sum (related to Newton's binomial formula)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-theorem

i was given the following question:

given n is a positve integer, calculate the given sum:
$$
{n \choose 1} -2{n \choose 2} +3{n \choose 3}+ \ldots +(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n {n \choose n}
$$

I looked at the expression and it reminds me of Newton's binom.. but i have no idea where to begin.. can someone help me understand how should i approach this?

thank you

Comment: notice that $k{n\choose k} = n{n-1\choose k-1}$

Comment: thank you, but i still  dont understand how do i combine all the different chooses? i get that some of them overlap so everytime i subtract i also add by that amount

Comment: afterwards, use this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313832/a-combinatorial-proof-that-the-alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-is-zero

Comment: What's a binom and why are you using i, the  square root of minus one?

Comment: @Exodd i think i understand. so the answer is 1?

Comment: should be zero actually

Comment: Hint: Binomial theorem, differentiation.

Comment: Hint: no differentiation. Look at the binomial evaluation of $(1-1)^{n-1}$ and multiply it by $n$. Compare this to your given sum.